# Check for file size with JavaScript before uploading in IE9 Browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, flash, internet-explorer

Following is a part of my ASP.NET MVC :  When User tries to upload a file in IE 9  browser   it is throwing  error on this line  this.files[0].size;
because IE 9 browser does supoort html 5 api(FileReader)

```html
<input type="file" name="FileToUpload" id="FileToUpload"  style="width: 100%;" />

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
 $('#FileToUpload').bind('change', function () {
            
               var sizeInMB = '';
              
                   /* Other */
                      this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
                   var sizeInBytes = this.files[0].size;
                      var sizeInMB = (sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2);    2000
                    sizeInMB = $([sizeInBytes]).map(function () { return (this / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) })[0];
              
          
              
        });
```

so i happen to use this snippet When i execute this line
 $("#FileToUpload")[0].value i dont' get the file path i get this like this
(C:\fakepath\MORETHAN2gbticket.zip)

Is there any other way i can get file size For IE 9 browser .One way is can use Flash .Then For that i need to use plugin like ( uploadify Upload jQuery )
Is there any other i can get file size without using plugin 
Can anyone please guide me .

```html
    var file = $("#FileToUpload");
           var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
           var filePath = $("#FileToUpload")[0].value;
            var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
            var fileSize = objFile.size; //size in kb
```

Answer (score 0):

No! IE version 9 doesn't have FileReader api but a prototype named **File Api Lab**:

[image]

You can check the compatibility table here [@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

---

One suggestion is to use a fallback to get the fileSize from the server instead.

like:

```
if(IE > 9){
   // use FileApi
}else{
   // put a call to the server to get the 
   // file size. an ajax call would be fine.
}
```

Comment: If i do an ajax call and the file is more than 2 gb don't u think it will throw an error .Because in asp.net we can upload fie upto 2 gb  i want to disallow user to upload 2gb